# unable to run visual studio code as root on RHEL8

Tags: visual-studio-code, redhat, root

I cannot start Visual Studio Code version 1.42.1 as root on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.1 I have tried using the recommended path:

```
root# *code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"
root# *code --user-data-dir=/usr/foo/bar*
```

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.  Is it possible to configure root access from inside Visual studio or has anyone else got a working command from Redhat Enterprise Linux 8 cli?

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Why are you trying to run an editor as root?

Comment: Omair,  I have my reasons,  generally because the permission is set in such a way that it is available to the webserver.  chown down on nginx user.  I have tried using a group but it doesn't work.  Threefore I want to edit by root as if I do this with my current username,  ever time I modify a piece of code I have to authenticate with sudo to save.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around by logging in with root on the RHEL 8 server,  This enables me to run code as root.

I would still be interested in knowing how to run as root from my default user to load code with root permissions.